# R: Function for calculations based on column name

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this (just a subsample)

```
Year <- c(1990,1991,1992)
Country_1_v1 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4)
Country_1_v2 <- c(0.6,0.5,0.1)
Country_2_v1 <- c(1.2,1.4,1.1)
Country_2_v2 <- c(1.7,1.3,1.2)
```

So, I have two columns (v1, v2) for both countries (i.e. 4 columns) over a specific time period. Now, I want to calculate v1/v2 for EVERY country. Since I have 25 countries I do not want to use mutate.

Is there a quick way to build a function that does it for me? I am not really familiar with functions and would appreciate any help!

Right now my column names are "'Country Name'.x" for v1 and "'Country Name'.y" for v2.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your actual data - dataframe?

Comment: This is a job for `pivot_longer`, doing you calcs and then `pivot_wider` again (both from tidyverse package).

Answer (score 1):

Transforming TO's vectors into a data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(Year = c(1990,1991,1992),
                  Country_1_v1 = c(0.2,0.3,0.4),
                  Country_1_v2 = c(0.6,0.5,0.1),
                  Country_2_v1 = c(1.2,1.4,1.1),
                  Country_2_v2 = c(1.7,1.3,1.2))
```

You can then make use of tidyverse's flexible approach for pivoting. You need to create a template for that that tells us how you would want to transform the old variables into the new ones (I'm curious if there's a solution that can directly transform the data into pivot_longer without the template).

```
template <- data.frame(.name  = colnames(dat)[-1],
                       Country = c("Country_1", "Country_1", "Country_2", "Country_2"),
                      .value = c("v1", "v2", "v1", "v2"))
```

This looks like:

```
         .name   Country .value
1 Country_1_v1 Country_1     v1
2 Country_1_v2 Country_1     v2
3 Country_2_v1 Country_2     v1
4 Country_2_v2 Country_2     v2
```

So each of your original columns is split up into a) a country column and b) in two separate va and v2 columns.

Now you can do your calculation and transfer back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  pivot_longer_spec(template) %>%
  mutate(ratio = v1/v2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Country,
              values_from = c(v1, v2, ratio),
              names_glue = "{Country}_{.value}")
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
   Year Country_1_v1 Country_2_v1 Country_1_v2 Country_2_v2 Country_1_ratio Country_2_ratio
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1  1990          0.2          1.2          0.6          1.7           0.333           0.706
2  1991          0.3          1.4          0.5          1.3           0.6             1.08 
3  1992          0.4          1.1          0.1          1.2           4               0.917
```

Note the columns are not in the same order as in the original data frame anymore. But this could be solved with a relocating pipe.